# Can ISP block access point configuration at their side?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-access-point, isp, wireless-extender

I have two homes on the same building flour. Earlier ISP administration allowed me to use single connection in both homes. So ISP connection was provided to one home and then I had a router configured as AP at another home. The AP-router is connected to Host/main router by wired connection.

Now the ISP administration is changed and it is not supportive of such extension of network to another home. Can they block such extension at their side, may be by some configuration.

Or such AP configuration is completely invisible to them and they cannot control it at their side?

Also, earlier I configured this AP-router as normal non-AP router. Due to this I was not able to connect devices in home from another home. Can ISP disallow such configuration with some configuration at their side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ISPs provide routers. They keep ownership and they can change its configuration remotely. In this situation, the ISP could disable Wi-Fi on the device.

If you install your own (NAT) router (either in place of an ISP-provided router or behind it), the ISP cannot control it. They also cannot directly investigate the network behind it, like whether you have Wi-Fi enabled or whomever you may be sharing your internet access with. They could analyze your network traffic but that’s generally not worth it.

An evil ISP could theoretically block additional wireless access points on the network (with collateral damage, because the entire switch port would be blocked), but detecting them would require scanning the network. Pretty sure no ISP would bother.

If I understand correctly, only the third paragraph applies to your situation (ISP-provided router + AP on local network).

Comment: Let me know if I understand it correct: What ISPs own is the host-router. In my case they dont really own it. I bought it online and they just added a config in it. Regardless of that, I felt AP-router is not at all exposed to them, right? (PS: I used [this](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/1384/) page for configuration.)

Comment: Yes, if you own the router at the network perimeter, the ISP is locked out. That’s the second paragraph then.

Comment: I didnt get "at the network perimeter, the ISP is locked out". You mean to say if I own the router at network endpoint, ISP cannot do much for blocking how I use it (whether I connect AP to it or not)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.